# Interrupting all threads by CTRL+C

Tags: python, multithreading

When I press CTRL+C to interrupt program it quits only main thread and new created still working. How to terminate all threads?

```
import threading, time

def loop():
    while True:
        print("maked thread")
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target = loop)
t.start()

while True:
    print("loop")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use use a flag and have the thread check the flag for exit, while in the main thread you should catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and set the flag.

```
import threading, time
import sys

stop = False

def loop():
    while not stop:
        print("maked thread")
        time.sleep(1)
    print('exiting thread')

t = threading.Thread(target = loop)
t.start()

try:
    while True:
        print("loop")
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stop = True
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: It's working pretty good, but I found simpler solution. Just add "daemon=True" parameter to threading.Thread.